# Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression

Tags: c#, база-данных

Язык: с#

Есть поле для ввода текста, его текст хранится в TextBox.Text

Есть бд(Microsoft access), там есть столбец sub и он может хранить текст

Есть запрос:`string query_sub = "UPDATE bd SET sub = " + TextBox.Text + " WHERE id = 1 ";`

Строки для выполнения запроса:

`OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query_sub, connection);`

`command.ExecuteNonQuery();`

Когда в `TextBox.Text` тоесть в поле для ввода вводится только цифры все работает отлично, но если появляются символы то появляется ошибка 
`Syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'Текст который ввели в поле'`

Я уже долго немогу понять как это исправить, мне нужно чтобы при вводе символов небыло ошибок и выполнялся запрос

Comment: Используйте _параметры_

Comment: Как? Можете показать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что строковое значение должно быть заключено в кавычки.

Вам может помочь такой вариант

```
string query_sub = String.Format("UPDATE bd SET sub = '{0}' WHERE id = 1 ", TextBox.Text);
```

Comment: А если в самом строковом значении есть кавычка? Нужно её заэскейпить. Но проще и надёжнее использовать параметры.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так

```
public void Update(String connectionString)
{
    var text= TextBox.Text;

    using (var connection = new OleDbConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
        {
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE bd SET sub = '@text' WHERE id = 1;";
            command.Parameters.AddRange(new OleDbParameter[] 
            {
                new OleDbParameter("@text", text)
            });

            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }    
    }   
}
```